# Problemas con Autofac con Repositorio Genérico y Capa de Servicios

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inyeccion-de-dependencias, webapi, autofac

Estoy siguiendo la arquitectura Onion de Jeffrey Palermo, tengo 3 capas:

- Core: donde estan las entidades e interfaces de repositorio y servicios.
- Infrastructure: donde esta la implementacion del repositorio. Esta capa consume unicamente al Core.
- Services: donde esta implementacion de las interfaces de servicios. Esta capa consume al Core y a Infrastructure.
- Api: Es un proyecto de WebAPi que consume a la capa de servicios. Esta capa consume a todas las enteriores

Siguiendo con el concepto de Onion Architecture cada capa se comunica con otra por medio de Inyeccion de dependecias. Para lograr esto estoy utilizando la libreria de autofac y en mi proyecto api tengo la siguiente clase para configurar las dependecias:

```
public class IoCConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>));
        builder.RegisterType<DummyService>().As<IDummyService>();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

Mi clase de servicios esta construida de la siguiente manera:

```
public class DummyService : IDummyService
{
    IRepository<Estados> estadosRepo;

    public DummyService(IRepository<Estados> estadosRepo)
    {
        this.estadosRepo = estadosRepo;
    }

    public List<Estados> GetAll()
    {
        var aaa = new Estados() { IdEstado = 1, Nombre = "aaa" };
        var bbb = new Estados() { IdEstado = 2, Nombre = "bbb" };

        var estados = new List<Estados>();
        estados.Add(aaa);
        estados.Add(bbb);

        //estadosRepo.GetById(1);

        return estados;
    }
}
```

Y finalmente el repositorio Esta contruido de la siguente manera:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Context context = null;
    private DbSet<T> db = null;

    public Repository(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        db = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void GetById(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Ahora, todo bien hasta aquí. En los controladores del proyecto webapi estoy inyectando las interfaces de los servicios, esto lo hago por medio de la librería autofac y todo funciona correctamente.

El problema esta cuando a los metodos de la capa de servicios le inyecto la dependencia del repositorio, aqui es cuando la aplicacion me regresa un error, concretamente me regresa esto:

> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DummyController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Gallo.Api.Controllers.DummyController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DummyService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Gallo.Core.Services.IDummyService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = Repository`1 (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Gallo.Core.Repositories.IRepository`1[[Gallo.Infrastructure.Data.Estados, Gallo.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Gallo.Infrastructure.Repositories.Repository`1[Gallo.Infrastructure.Data.Estados]' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Gallo.Infrastructure.Data.Context context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Gallo.Infrastructure.Data.Context)'. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro: no hay ningún constructor sin parámetros en la clase Repository. El construcor público necesita una instancia de Context. Para solucionarlo, necesitas modificar el registro de Repository en el contenedor DI:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>))
       .WithParameter("context", new Context());
```

Comment: Implemente la solucion que me propones y la apliacion funciono correctamente. Muchisimas gracias!